# derivation of first order PDE solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Holla, everybody!

I'm studying first order PDE and I have difficulties figuring out a few points. Will appreciate any help!

So, say, we have a first order inhomogeneous equation:
$$X_1(x_1,...,x_n,u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+...+X_n(x_1,...,x_n,u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}= T(x_1, ...,x_n,u)$$
We write down a system of ODEs in order to find characteristics:
$$\frac{dx_1}{ds} = X_1,...,\frac{dx_n}{ds} = X_n, \frac{du}{ds}=T$$
Then we write a symmetric form of a system down:
$$\frac{dx_1}{X_1(x_1,...,x_n,u)} =...=\frac{dx_2}{X_n(x_1,...,x_n,u)} = \frac{du}{T} = ds$$
**The first question: where did $ds$ come away?**
All the books use symmetric form without $ds$:
$$\frac{dx_1}{X_1(x_1,...,x_n,u)} =...=\frac{dx_2}{X_n(x_1,...,x_n,u)} = \frac{du}{T}$$
Then we found n first integrals $\psi_1,...,\psi_n$ of the system - it's curves along which solution $u$ has constant value, and the problem in constructing the solution $u$ is that we don't know how does $u$ change between these curves.

And there without any derivation books say that a general solution of PDE is $\Phi(\psi_1,...,\psi_n)=0$, where $\Phi$ - arbitrary function.
**The second question: where did it come from?**

Lets consider our equation to be homogeneous, so $T \equiv 0$, then we have system
$$\frac{dx_1}{X_1(x_1,...,x_n,u)} =...=\frac{dx_2}{X_n(x_1,...,x_n,u)} = \frac{du}{0}$$
One of its first integrals is $u=const$, so our solution shall be
$$\Phi(\psi_1,...,\psi_{n-1},u)=0$$
And then it is rewritten, saying that we resolve $u$, $u = \Phi(\psi_1,...,\psi_{n-1}) $
**The third question: why we can resolve $u$ in such a  way?**